# Reading from a textarea element using StringReader ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textarea, stringreader

Trying to read from a the html textarea element  in order to perform a data conversion.

my Text Area Code

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="txtArea@(i)">
```

Trying to implement it into this method

```
  public ActionResult About()
    {
        Document document = new Document();

        try
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/") + "downloads/" + "print.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();

            List<ielement> htmlarraylist = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
                              new StringReader(txtArea.Text), null);

            for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
            {
                document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);

            }

            Paragraph mypara = new Paragraph();
            document.Add(mypara);

            document.Close();

            Response.Redirect("~/downloads/print.pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtArea.Text = ex.Message;
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

}
But I get an error on each instance of `txtArea.Text` how would I implement it?

Error: textArea does not exists in the current context

View Code

```
   ` @{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
    int i = 1;
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>
<table style="background-color: lightgreen; border: solid 2px black;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Name</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Size</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Preview</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>Read File</b>
        </td>
         <td>
            <b>Convert File</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var file in Model)
    {    
        <tr>
            <td>
                @file.Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @(file.Size / 1000) KB
            </td>
            <td>
                @(file.extension)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="btnreadfile@(i)" name="@file.Name" class='btnClick' type="button" value="Read File"/>
                <textarea  rows="4" cols="50" class="txtArea@(i)" name ="txtArea">@(ViewBag.DataVal)
</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="btnconvertfile@(i)" name="@file.Name" class='btnClick' type="button" value="Convert File"/>

            </td>
        </tr>   
        i++;
    }
</table>

<textarea></textarea>
<aside>
    <h3>Aside Title</h3>
    <p>
        Use this area to provide additional information.
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
</aside>

<script>
    $(".btnClick").click(function () {
        var selectedId = $(this).attr("id").replace("btnreadfile", "");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ReadTextFile",
            type: "GET",
            data: { fileName: $(this).attr("name") },
            DataType: "text",
            success: function (str) {
                $(".txtArea" + selectedId).val(str);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
</script>`
```

[image]

What i'm trying to achieve is at the click of the convert button to convert the text inside the textarea into a pdf file.

Comment: Tried the following `<textarea id="TextArea1" rows="4" cols="50" class="txtArea@(i)" runat="server" >
</textarea>`  & `new StringReader(TextArea1.Text), null);` still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because there's no "textArea" variable defined anywhere.

MVC does not work the same as ASPX.  All your form controls need to have a name, and those names either have to correspond to the property names on a model object that the view is using (and the controller has to accept the model object as a parameter), or they need to correspond to parameter names of the controller method.  Your code needs some work.

First, define a model class with a property to hold the value of the textarea:

```
namespace YourProject.Models
{
    class AboutModel
    {
        public string MyText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

At the top of your view, use the model:

```
@model YourProject.Models.AboutModel
```

In your view, give your textarea a name that corresponds to the property of the model that will hold the value of the textarea, and initialize the textarea's value to the value of that property:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="MyText">@Model.MyText</textarea>
```

Give your controller method a parameter which can accept the model:

```
public ActionResult About(AboutModel model)
```

In the body of controller method, you need to handle two cases:

1. If the model is null, that means the view is being called for the first time and needs to be initialized.
2. If the model is not null, that means the form has been posted back to the controller with data.

Something like this:

```
public ActionResult About(AboutModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        model = new AboutModel();
        model.MyText = "whatever you want the initial value of the text are to be";
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            string textAreaValue = model.MyText;

            // do your processing on the textAreaValue here

            // if you want to redirect, do this:
            return Redirect("~/downloads/print.pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            model.MyText = ex.Message;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Add more properties to the model if you have other information that you want to send back and forth between the view and the controller.

Hope this helps.  I would recommend finding a good tutorial on MVC if this isn't making sense.

Comment: I get an error on my view if i put `@model YourProject.Models.AboutModel`  since i'm using a @foreach statement how do i fix this?

Comment: What error?  And it would greatly help if you edited your question to show your view code.  Right now I have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: Error is foreach cannot operate because model does not contain GetEnumarot definition. Updated with ViewCode

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the textarea in server side.because the control must have runat="server" mode.
If you are using MVC then you need to pick the control in server side with the nameof the control in HttpPost action.

If you want to assign value to the textarea then you need a property of ViewBag to do this.

so do this :

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="txtArea@(i)" name="txtArea">@(ViewBag.DataVal)</textarea>
```

and server side code :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult About()
{
    Document document = new Document();

    try
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/") + "downloads/" + "print.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        List<ielement> htmlarraylist = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
                          new StringReader(txtArea.Text), null);

        for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
        {
            document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);

        }

        Paragraph mypara = new Paragraph();
        document.Add(mypara);

        document.Close();

        Response.Redirect("~/downloads/print.pdf");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.DataVal = ex.Message;
        return View();
    }

}
```

Comment: I still get textArea does not exists in the current context error with this method.

Comment: sorry i forgot the first one code for textarea. Get the value from textarea by Request["txtArea"]

Comment: Yes. List<ielement> htmlarraylist = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
                          new StringReader(Request["txtArea"]), null);

Comment: I get the error: not all code paths return a value on my About method.

Comment: public ActionResult About().This method needs to return an value type of "ActionResult".In your catch return this thing but try block is not.so instead of Response.Redirect("~/downloads/print.pdf"); write Return Redirect("~/downloads/print.pdf");

Comment: Could you help me complete the script for my ConvertFile Button, as it does nothing atm when i click it. `<script>
    $(".btnClick").click(function () {
        var selectedId = $(this).attr("id").replace("btnConvertfile", "");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Shared/About",
            type: "",
            data: {},
            DataType: "pdf",
            success: function (str) {
                $("~/downloads/" + selectedId).val(str);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
</script>`